# How to know if line intersects with a circle on google map using location points

Tags: android, android-mapview

Lets say I have the locations (Lat/Lng) A,B and C.  Locations A and B are the end points of a line. C is the center of the circle with Radius R. How can I know if Line A-B intersects with the circle (regardless of the number of points or intersections)? I just need to know if there is intersection or not

Thank you

[image]

Comment: basic geometry: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073336/circle-line-segment-collision-detection-algorithm

Comment: I checked that before but the problem that they are x,y cooordinates. This is Lat/long. The difference is that the distance between them  (by doing the d2 = y2 + x2 will return it in terms of location units. While the R distance (circle) is in terms of the meters.

Comment: Maybe you can transform the coordinates to x/y: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983099/converting-longitude-latitude-to-x-y-coordinate

Comment: I wish there would be an answer for the problem as opposed to comment