# Intersection of two Moving Objects

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to use the answer provided here: [Intersection of two Moving Objects with Latitude/Longitude Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250215/intersection-of-two-moving-objects-with-latitude-longitude-coordinates)

But I have some questions..

What is this angle:

```
var angle = Math.PI + dir - target.dir
```

I was thinking that the angle that should be used in the law of cosines is already "alpha or target.dir".. What is that line doing? Also in these two steps:

```
 var x = target.x + target.vel * time * Math.cos(target.dir); 
 var y = target.y + target.vel * time * Math.sin(target.dir);
```

Shouldn't the code be using the angle between x- or y-axis and the target velocity vector? Why is the author using alpha here?

[image]

Comment: Great that you posted it as a question! I pinged the original author, maybe he'll give us some insights ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Thanks for letting me know. I'll have a look at it later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is this angle:
>
> ```
> var angle = Math.PI + dir - target.dir
> ```

The variable named *angle* is indeed the angle *alpha*. Because the direction *dir* is the direction from chaser to target, and we need it the other way round for this calculation, we add π to it before we subtract *target.dir*.

Maybe using the word *angle* as a variable name was a bit vague; I'll change it to *alpha*, the name I used for this angle in the images.

> Shouldn't the code be using the angle between x- or y-axis and the target velocity vector? Why is the author using alpha here?
>
> ```
> var x = target.x + target.vel * time * Math.cos(target.dir);  
> var y = target.y + target.vel * time * Math.sin(target.dir);
> ```

We are indeed using *target.dir*, which is the direction of the target, i.e. the angle between the x-axis and the target vector, to calculate the coordinates of the interception point, and not the angle alpha.

Comment: Thank you for your reply..
First, I thought, as many of the readers I guess, that the given target.dir is already alpha as it's shown in the graphs. I think you may need to declare that target.dir is the angle between the x-axis and the target velocity vector, and also include it in the graphs for calcification.. (I have attached a graph for suggested edits.)

Second, based on the graphs I see that alpha just equals dir - target.dir.. I have checked the law of cosines again and it just uses alpha, I cannot get in why you want it the other way round by adding a pi ?

Comment: @isso11 As described in the original answer, the directions use the JavaScript convention with 0 = right and Pi/2 = up, so all directions are given as angles with the X-axis. The way `dir` is calculated, it is the direction from chaser to target, but for the cosine rule, we're looking from the target to the chaser, so we add Pi to switch the direction.